# ORA error after TRIDION_CM content replication

Tags: web8.5

Post content sync from PROD to stage we are facing ORA-01403: no data found error for Stored Procedure "EDA_ITEMS.READ_ITEM"

A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_ITEMS.READ_ITEM".
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "TRIDION_CM.EDA_ITEMS", line 1136
ORA-06512: at "TRIDION_CM.EDA_ITEMS", line 1315
ORA-06512: at line 1

Answer (score 1):

This looks like something you should take up with your Oracle DBA. IF there's "no data found", it seems likely that your "content sync" hasn't gone well.

Comment: Yes @Dominic
Looks like the procedures are not properly imported.

We have asked our DBA to take a fresh clone of CM database and import to our stage environment.

Answer (score 0):

The issue fixed after redoing the content sync.

we checked and found procedures are missed.
SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE IN ('PROCEDURE') and OBJECT_NAME like'%ITEM_READ%';